# The "OutputFiles" parameter is not supported by the "XamlGTask" task

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-devops

Xamarin forms 3.4
In my solution, apart from the 3 projects that are created by defauly (Common, Android and iOS), I have another .net standard project (a library) that I'm using for ViewModels, services etc. with the name "Core". I'm using Azure DevOps to build and deploy for both Android and iOS

In this "Core" project, I have included a NuGet package that is using an older version of Xamarin.Forms (v. 3.0)

During development, I don't have any problems building the and running it.

When, I'm trying to build the app in Azure DevOps for the iOS, I'm getting the error `error MSB4064: The "OutputFiles" parameter is not supported by the "XamlGTask" task.`

It seems that this error is being produced because the solution is referencing different versions of Xamarin.Forms. In order to overcome the problem I need to add to the "Core" project the following reference in order to "align" the versions.

`<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="3.4.0.1008975" />`

Adding this line solves the issue with building the app for iOS in Azure DevOps but by adding this lines creates a problem in the Android version of the app. No building issues but when running the app on an Android device, doesn't pass the splash screen. (without the reference of Xamarin.Forms works fine)

I have to add the reference when building for iOS and remove it when building for Android.

I guess that the question is obvious. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Did you used third-part  nuget packages? Are there pulling in an incorrect version of XF?

Comment: Yes, I do. I state that in the second paragraph of the post. I use a NuGet package that uses XF v.3.0